# Installing find spark in virtual environment

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv

I am using `pyenv` to create a virtual environment.

My pyenv packages are located under the project `bio` in `/.pyenv/versions/bio/lib/python3.7/site-packages`

I installed `findspark` using below

```
pip install findspark  #it was installed successfully.
```

I am able to see the below files in the packages directory.

```
findspark-1.4.2.dist-info
findspark.py
```

However, when I launch Jupyter notebook from the pyenv directory, I get an error message

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
```

> **ImportError: No module named findspark**

Can you please help me understand why do we get this error despite the pip install being successful?

My `which Jupyter` returns the below path (both in terminal & in jupyter notebook)

`/home/abcd/.pyenv/shims/jupyter

Answer (score 1):

Jupyter notebook does not get launched from within the `virtualenv` even though you activated the `virtualenv` in the terminal session.

If you `import sys` and print out `sys.executable`, you'll realise that the first value of the python executable isn't that of the `virtualenv`.

You need to add the `python` of the `virtualenv` as a kernel.

```
$ virtualenv -p python3 pysparkvenv
$ source pysparkvenv/bin/activate
(pysparkvenv) $ pip install findspark jupiter  # etc.

(pysparkvenv) $ python -m ipykernel install --user

(pysparkvenv) $ which python
/home/disciple/Desktop/sample/pysparkvenv/bin/python

# make the necessary change to the python path
(pysparkvenv) $ sudo /home/disciple/Desktop/sample/pysparkvenv/bin/python -m ipykernel install --name pysparkvenv
```

This will create a new kernel which will be available in the dropdown list.

You can check if the kernel was created like this

```
$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  python3        /home/disciple/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
  pysparkvenv    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/pysparkvenv
```

After this, you can launch `jupyter notebook` from anywhere and a new kernel will be available. Select this and you'll have all the modules you installed inside the virtualenv.

[image: pysparkvenv kernel]

Comment: Hi, No, I am able to launch jupyter notebook that was installed in `virtualenv`

Comment: Because `findspark` is not installed in the global python. It is only installed in the environment.

Comment: The `python3` kernel is not the one from the env you created. So it won't have any of the modules you install inside the env

Comment: You can either install everything globally, which I don't think you want to do since you're using pipenv. Or install another kernel for that particular env.

Comment: Sorry, I have installed `pyspark`, `jupyter notebook`, `find spark` everything installed in virtual env and no am trying to use usual import command in `import findspark` in jupyter

Comment: You can give it a try and launch the notebook with the pyspark kernel and see if it solves your problem.